# Can I disable access to JS APIs in the browser such as highres timers?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, time, meltdown, spectre

In the wake of recent news of CPU bugs like Meltdown and Spectre which rely on precise(-ish) measurments of elapsed time, I find myself in the mood for disabling things like `window.performance.now()` in my browser (apart from other mitigations, obviously).

- Is it possible to disable a particular JS API function in either recent Firefox or Chromium? (Preferably by configuration, but I'm also up for compiling from sources if needed.)
- If so, does it make sense to do so?

Comment: It certainly makes sense, Firefox is going to reduce timer resolution because of this: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/01/03/mitigations-landing-new-class-timing-attack/

Comment: `performance.now()` isn't as high-res as you might think: `performance.now()-performance.now()` == -0.005 in chrome

Comment: @dandavis That difference is not representative of the timer's actual obtainable resolution, refer to the Mozilla statement linked by mr.spuratic and the paper linked therein.

Comment: @kralyk: how is calling it twice in a row not representative, or is there a way to call it faster?

Comment: @dandavis There isn't a way to call it faster, but you can still extract high precision by measuring the timer rounding edges. If you want to know how this is done please read the [linked paper](https://gruss.cc/files/fantastictimers.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Before the browsers get patched, you can write a [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) to replace these DOM objects with dummies or delete the `performance` property altogether.

This is mostly a development feature and public website shouldn't need it to function anyways.

However, due to stupid "features" like NaCl/WebAssembly and WebGL, there may be many other ways to do a timing side channel attack in a browser.

Comment: Just a note: It may be difficult to truly make these properties inaccessible. The user script would need to run before any other code in every context (frames, web workers, etc.), and ensure they are not still accessible through object prototypes. An attacker might not go that far though.

Comment: don't forget about web workers: altered dom/bom handles will be fresh in the clean worker context.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: An extension could do the work?

Comment: @CrouchingKitten Maybe. I'm not really sure if either a user script or a Web Extension have the necessary API's.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: if it runs first the script only need to break/clobber the window property. A cleaver hacker can restore new copies, say from a new iframe's window object, but it should stop "drive bys"